# How to catch 500 error in Controller using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, guzzle, guzzle6

I need to connect to an API so I write a function:

```
try {
    $res4 = $client3->post('https://api.example.co.uk/Book', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ajhsdbjhasdbasdbasd',
        ],
        'json' => [
            'custFirstName' => $FirstName,
            'custLastName' => $Surname,
            'custPhone' => $Mobile,
            'custEmail' => $Email,
        ]
    ]);
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    $item->update(['status' => 'Problems at step3']);
    Mail::raw('Problem at STEP 3', function ($message) use ($serial) {
        $message->from('asd.asd@gmail.com', 'asd.asd@gmail.com');
        $message->subject('We got a problem etc.');
        $message->to('john.smith@gmail.com');
    });
}
```

As you can see I need to make a call to API but in the case when API is down I write catch functions.

But now when API is down and API return '500 Internal Error' this function is just crashed ...

My question is why catch dont handle it?

How I can handle errors - when API is down or bad request... WHy catch{} doesn't work?

UPDATE: here is my laravel.log

```
[2018-10-25 14:51:04] local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `POST https://api.example.co.uk/Book` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
{"message":"An error has occured. Please contact support."}
 in /home/public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /home/public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
```

Comment: Please check laravel log in folder /storage/log/laravel.log

Comment: It might not be a `ClientException` catch the root Exception `Exception` instead

Comment: Check your log and post the full error here.

Comment: 500 internal error is not an exception that was thrown by the way.

Comment: from API i got error: 
ServerException in RequestException.php line 107:
Server error: `POST https://api.exampe.co.uk/Book` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
{"message":"An error has occured. Please contact support."}

Comment: I update the question. Please take a look!

Comment: is it your own API or someone else's?

Comment: someone else API

Comment: @AleksPer ok, but I am saying in general, you won't find an exception that was thrown in case of 500 internal server error. Also, the reason it wasn't catched is because you need to catch the superclass `Exception` or at least `ServerException`.

Comment: Hmm. A `4xx` is user error, ie 400 you sent crap data to them. a `5xx` is **their** error

Comment: If **server error response** you can catch it using `catch (Guzzle\Http\Exception\ServerErrorResponseException $e) { ... }`

Comment: What is the way to handle any error I got?

Comment: just `catch (Exception $e){var_dump($e); exit;}` That will catch any and every exception. If that doesn't help email them and send them the request

Comment: I try to use just catch (Exception $e) but again I got error. I need to just send ALERT email if there is a error and continue with function ... I dont need to crash the function!

Comment: @AleksPer what is `$client3`?

Comment: @AleksPer I just realized the reason `catch` isn't working in your case is because this exception was thrown on their server, so you can't catch it at your end.

Comment: but all what I want is to if there is some error to do not crash the function, becuase this is on of many steps there

Comment: @AleksPer if you are talking with me, you will need to mention my name, else I won't be notified. What is the HTTP response code that you got? Probably, you can try with that.

Answer (score 6):

The problem are namespaces here, instead of:

```
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
```

you should rather use:

```
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
```

Otherwise PHP assumes that class is in current namespacase, so in fact when you used `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` in fact you probably used `App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` and such exception obviously won't be thrown by Guzzle.

Comment: no, this is not the solution, because I got the same error again. All I want is to catch error from API and update $item, also to send ALERT email to some email address

Comment: @AleksPer Oh ok, so in error log you have `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException`, so you can replace with this one. However because you might have different exceptions, it's better to replace with `} catch (\Exception $e) {` to really catch any exception that might happen here.

Comment: catch (\Exception $e) { will catch any error on API's ? I tried and seems that works good for now

Comment: @AleksPer Yes, it should catch any exception that appear. But if you are using PHP 7, even better is to use `\Throwable` just in case -  see http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php

Comment: This worked for me with 3rd party library's Exception.

Answer (score 2):

The exception that is fired is a ServerException instance, and catch block tries to catch ClientException.

```
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> in your app/exceptions/handler.php file, update the render method like this one.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
    if ($exception instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException) {
        return your_response();
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

> This approach worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're trying to catch an exception, when you should actually be trying to catch an error. In your catch block try using `\Error` instead of `\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException`.